The edit button on doesnt do anything. How can i make it work
The edit button is supposed to edit the entered data on the table but it doesn't do anything when clicked.
Everything in this code works but the edit button doesn't actually edit or do anything from the database in Firestore.
// Edit button pressed
$(document).on('click', '.editBtn', function() {
  const id = $(this).data('id');
  const docRef = doc(db, "movie-review", id);
  docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      const data = doc.data();
      $("#movieName").val(data.movie_name);
      $("#director").val(data.director);
      $("#releasedate").val(data.release_date);
      $("#movieRating").val(data.movie_rating);
      // Delete existing data
      deleteDoc(docRef).then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
});


// Update button pressed
$("#updateButton").click(function() {
  const id = $("#editReviewId").val();
  const docRef = doc(db, "movie-review", id);
  setDoc(docRef, {
    movie_name: $("#editMovieName").val(),
    director: $("#editDirector").val(),
    release_date: $("#editReleaseDate").val(),
    movie_rating: parseInt($("#editMovieRating").val())
  }).then(() => {
    // Close the edit review modal
    $('#editReviewModal').modal('hide');
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
  });
});

// Delete button pressed
$(document).on('click', '.deleteBtn', function() {
  const id = $(this).data('id');
  deleteDoc(doc(db, "movie-review", id)).then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
  });
});


Maybe also share the HTML in a snippet so that we can reproduce the issue

Firstly, there's not enough context around the problem here to help you. 'It doesn't work' isn't enough information. What debugging have you done? At what point does the logic flow deviate from what you expect? In the first instance I'd suggest you open devtools and check for errors in the console, then put some console.log() lines in to your code to determine the logic flow and to check what the variables contain during runtime.

https://github.com/birat54/movie this is the full code

As mentioned in the firebase documentation, I have just modified the function as per the document and it works fine.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data
Please check the Sections named Get a Document. You have to use the getDoc function instead of "get".
I am attaching the modified version.
$(document).on('click', '.editBtn', function () {
    const id = $(this).data('id');
    const docRef = doc(db, "movie-review", id);
    const docSnap = getDoc(docRef);
    docSnap.then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists()) {
            const data = doc.data();
            $("#movieName").val(data.movie_name);
            $("#director").val(data.director);
            $("#releasedate").val(data.release_date);
            $("#movieRating").val(data.movie_rating);
            // Delete existing data
            deleteDoc(docRef).then(() => {
                console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
});

